# Execute curl commands read from a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

I have a text file which contains curl calls inside. They are all separated by new-line breaks which helps me when it comes to reading the file line by line accordingly. My problem is that I am not sure how to trigger the curl calls to execute. Right now its behavior is to print to screen like it was just another string of chars?

Example of data.txt :

```
curl -X GET "https://www.google.com"
curl -X GET "https://www.facebook.com"
```

My script :

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=$'\n'
while read -r line
do
    echo $line
    makingCurlCall=$(echo "$line")
    echo "$makingCurlCall"
done < "data.txt"
```

It will only give the output of the lines and not actually making the curl calls.

Output:

```
curl -X GET "https://www.google.com"
curl -X GET "https://www.google.com"
curl -X GET "https://www.facebook.com"
curl -X GET "https://www.facebook.com"
```

Comment: `data.txt` already appears to be the script you want. Just execute it: `bash data.txt`.

Comment: Thanks. Agreed, but I will be doing some sanitation with SED once I make those calls in another script.

Comment: @chepner have been the only person who understood the question XD. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 5):

You are not executing the `curl` command contained in the line read from the input file.  You could do that by changing this line:

```
makingCurlCall=$(echo "$line") => this simply displays the command and not execute it
```

to

```
makingCurlCall=$(eval "$line")
```

or

```
makingCurlCall=$("$line")
```

`eval` is more appropriate if the command contained in the string has any meta characters that need to be interpreted by the shell.  For example, `>`, `<`, and `$`.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your script with this slightly modified version

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=$'\n'
while read -r line
do
    echo $line
    $line
done < "data.txt"
```

All `echo` does is output its arguments to standard output (which means showing them on screen in your case).

Expanding a variable (like `$line` above) will actually execute it as a command.  Because the lines in your file are properly quoted, it should work.